# Trying to install TensorFlow- GPU...failed with ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow GPU 1.12.0 (using pip), I am using cuda 9.0, windows 10, python 3.6, nvidia GTX 1080. I am stuck with ImportError.
Can anyone please guide me? Thanks!

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\station\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\station\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\station\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\station\venv\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\station\venv\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for sharing your responses. I was able to fix the issue by adding correct cuda path to my environment variable. Specifically, I added ***cuda, lib*** and ***include*** folders to environment and was able to successfully import TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

hey bro try to install tensorflow on his version 1.5

pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow-gpu==1.5
on his version is compatible

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some issue is there with tensorflow 1.12.0 +Python 3.6.0 + win10

Working fine with conda tensorflow.

below steps worked for me for pip tensorflow.

uninstall tensorflow replace your python version with 3.6.1 install latest version of tensorflow(1.13.0)

For installing Tensorflow follow below link:- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Python 3.6.0
2. tensorflow-gpu 1.13.0rc2
3. protobuf 3.6.0
4. CUDA 10.0 Toolkit
5. cuDNN 10.0